# Postgres DB on Ubuntu (AWS) - queries not returning for hours

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have a Postgres DB in my Mac Book Pro. Here are some basic queries and the execution times.

```
levi=# select count(1) from publishers;
  count   
----------
 19750023
(1 row)

Time: 5724.240 ms

levi=# select count(1) from publishers where publisher_id is null;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)

Time: 4056.290 ms
```

I have a second Postgres DB installed on Ubuntu on AWS, same tables, same columns, same indexes, same number of rows per table. The same queries on the Ubuntu server never returns, not even after several hours. No errors either. The server has 16GB of memory and 100 GB disk space. The data_directory is set in the config file to use this 100GB storage.

Both databases are designated as development, no application or users are using these databases except me running queries as the db owner.
Both databases (Mac and Ubuntu) were loaded using the COPY command and CSV files. Some other auxiliary tables were loaded with INSERT AS SELECT statements which completed on ubuntu accordingly with the expected time (similar to the time elapsed on my Mac).

On the Ubuntu I changed only these parameters to match the settings of the similar Postgres DB on my Mac:

```
effective_cache_size: from 128 MB to  4 GB
maintenance_work_mem: from  16 MB to 64 MB
work_mem:             from   1 MB to  4 MB
```

What is wrong here?

### edit 1: EXPLAIN

```
explain select count(1) from publishers;
QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate (cost=1292192.43..1292192.44 rows=1 width=0)
-> Seq Scan on publishers (cost=0.00..1146466.94 rows=58290194 width=0)
(2 rows) 

explain select count(1) from publishers where publisher_id is null;
QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate (cost=1292192.43..1292192.44 rows=1 width=0)
-> Seq Scan on publishers (cost=0.00..1146466.94 rows=58290194 width=0)
Filter: (publisher_id IS NULL)
(3 rows)

explain select count(1) from wokas where author_id is null;
                               QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1348708.43..1348708.44 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on wokas  (cost=0.00..1248634.54 rows=40029554 width=0)
         Filter: (author_id IS NULL)
(3 rows)

postgres=# explain select count(1) from authors;
                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=965641.11..965641.12 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on authors  (cost=0.00..861030.89 rows=41844089 width=0)
(2 rows)

postgres=# explain select count(1) from authors where author_id is null;
                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=965715.30..965715.31 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on authors  (cost=0.00..861097.04 rows=41847304 width=0)
         Filter: (author_id IS NULL)
(3 rows)
```

Comment: add the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, please.

Comment: explain select count(1) from publishers;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1292192.43..1292192.44 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on publishers  (cost=0.00..1146466.94 rows=58290194 width=0)
(2 rows)

Comment: explain select count(1) from publishers where publisher_id is null;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=1292192.43..1292192.44 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on publishers  (cost=0.00..1146466.94 rows=58290194 width=0)
         Filter: (publisher_id IS NULL)
(3 rows)

Comment: I added those comments to your original question. I assume both of those are from your Mac? Can you edit your question and add output from the Ubuntu server too? You are using an expensive operation (whereless count), but I suspect you'd see big improvements by switching to [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/).

Comment: All the results posted for explain are from the Ubuntu server. I edited the question and added some others not returning. Those showing the count are from Mac since the Ubuntu never returns them. However Ubuntu returns those explain statements.

Comment: Run `vmstat 1` on AWS during queries. The `bi` and `bo` columns will report the total disk input/output in KB/s. Presumably you'll notice that they're unbearably low compared non-virtualized I/O.

Comment: Also you may locate the `pid` of postgres processes in charge of the queries through `pg_stat_activity` and `strace` these processes to see what they're doing in terms of system calls.

Comment: Apparently seems that session suffered broke pipes without surfacing the message. I will investigate this further. I don't have yet a clear conclusion.

Comment: I did couple minor changes in the network and connectivity area and things improved, for example I open port 5432 and some new rows in pg_hba file.

Comment: Now the select statements works better but I am running in long times with updates which in Postgres MVCC seems to be a problem for millions of records tables. I will close this and open probably another one. Thanks for all help and recommendations.

Comment: Have you indexed `author_id` and `publisher_id`? Those should not be a seq scan. For the others, any queries against the full table at that size will be slow no matter what.

Comment: No need to index these columns. count(1) uses the first column which is "id". This column is a PK and gets the values generated by a sequence. The PK is indexed. The queries are returning now very fast, I think the problem was at the server / network configuration level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the installation and handling large volumes of data in Postgres running Ubuntu and AWS is much different and pose more difficulties than foreseen.